# SQL: For each item in one column, count its corresponding values in another

Tags: sql

I have a table Pair(id1, id2) that looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+
|   id1   |   id2   |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       2 |
|       3 |       1 |
|       4 |       1 |
|       5 |       3 |
|       6 |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

I need to create a statement that will print each individual value form id2, along with a counter of the number of values that correspond to it. The output should look like this:

```
+---------+---------+
|   id2   |  Count  |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       3 |
|       3 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try to search for it on google?

I assume you did not, because you can find this pretty easily : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is it me or the solution is straightforward? Please study SQL 101 and show some effort first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
select id2, count(*) cnt 
from mytable group by id2
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Sirmyself from your source: "*Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith, even if they break these guidelines. It's not always obvious at first glance that a question is homework, especially when you're not expecting to see it here. It is a good idea to suggest editing the response in a comment.*"

Comment: Is there any way to account for zeroes? For example, including 4 5 6 in the id1 column, with 0s in id2?

Comment: If you only want to count for zeroes, you can add `where id2 = 0` before group by

Comment: @connor-s if you want to count linked data AND unlinked data, you can consider using a [`LEFT JOIN` statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) or a subquery. I would personally go for the join since it's simpler and more readable IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it - replace #temp with your table name:

```
   select a.id1 id2, count(*) [count]from #temp a 
   join #temp b on a.id1=b.id2
   group by a.id1
```